# AngularJS Dependency Injection when no dependencies

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Why does AngularJS require empty array `[]` when defining module having no dependencies. Angular DevTeam can check the second parameter, if `undefined` means no dependencies.

```
angular.module("app", [])
```

It gives weird error when `[]` is not passed.

My question is why they need empty array?

Comment: Please consider adding comment when downvoting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `angular.module('app')` with 1 parameter has a different function - to get an already existing module without having a code reference to it.

The reason this:

```
angular.module('app', []); // Define the module.
angular.module('app'); // Get the module.
```

works as well as this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []); // Define the module and assign to variable.
```